# Changing width on a Report's subform field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have tried the following VBA code in the [A Report] event handlers as well as in the SubForm eventhandlers and the Width does not change when I view the report.

REPORTS![A Report]![SubForm]![TextField].Width = 7920

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the size in Design Mode did not work. I had to change the size in Datasheet View for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you display the the subform in Continuous forms mode rather than Datasheet, you then have complete control of the size and location of each field.